# Datepicker for dynamically generated text boxes

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a scenario like this,

```
for( int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <input type="text" id="t"+i val=""/>
}
```

I want date picker for all the text boxes...How..?

Is it possible at the time of page loading..?

I tried like this,,

and after selecting date it should be set in respected text box

```
for( int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <input type="text" id="t"+i val=""/>
    <input type="hidden" id="h"+i val=""/>
}



<script>
$(function () {
    var updateValue = false;
    $('input:hidden[id^=h]').datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: 'Open calendar',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: '/imagesOnline/calendar.png',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

        changeYear: atrue,
        changeMonth: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            //how to set respected text field
            $('#ExpireDate').val(dateText);
        }
    });
    //Animate datepicker
    $("#AssignedPartnerOrgHidden1").datepicker("option", "showAnim", "show");

    //pointer mark on mouseover
    $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting the texboxes dynamically?

Comment: Yes, i am getiing text boxes dyanmically..

Comment: Then Try like this   :
     
      $('input[id^="t"]').datepicker();

Comment: Datepicker will come for all text boxes.. if i select a date it will fill all the fileds

Answer (score 0):

`$('input:text[id^=t]')` selects all elements with `input` type `text` and `id` starting with `t`

```
$('input:text[id^=t]').datepicker();
```

[attribute-contains-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

[**^** attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Updated after OP updated question

```
onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var id = this.id.replace('h','');
            $('#t'+id).val(dateText);
        }
```

Comment: It is working fine. But if i select a date it will all the text fields

Comment: @NiranjanReddy no this will not happen.

Comment: you site online ? if give a link. If not post the code your using

Comment: for( int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <input type="text" id="t"+i val=""/>
}

Comment: not this code datepicker code and it is better if you show your full code

Answer (score 0):

give it a class.. and **initailize datepicker again, after the input is appended**

```
 <input type="text" id="t"+i class="dynamicInput" val=""/>
```

and call this after it is appended

```
//code for inserting the input
$('.dynamicInput').datepicker();
```

without class you can use attribute selector

```
$('input[id^=t]').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Jquery datepicker plugin

see http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

This can be bound to the input tag that you are creating or to pre-existing onces

Some simple code

```
<script>
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
</script>

<html><input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="datepicker">
<input class="datepicker">
<input class="datepicker">
<input class="datepicker">
<input class="datepicker">
or 
for( int i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
    <input type="text" class = "datepicker " val=""/>
}
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Html:
<div class = "main_div"></div>
jQuery:
$(document).ready(function(){
for( var i=0; i < 5; i++)
{
$('.main_div').append('<input type="text"   class ="datepicker" val=""/><br/>');    
 }

$('.datepicker').each(function(i) {
    this.id = 'datepicker' + i;
}).datepicker();
});
Check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/6zfEY/51/
```